# How to return rows that matches the variant count in the same table?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query which gives me the TOP 10 rows,I want to change it to return only rows with the number of variant count meaning in this case..the variant count is 2 (QCAHLSWMTPL and QCAHLSWMTPLZ),how can I change it?how to get the unique variant count?

```
SELECT TOP 10 SoftwareImageBuild si, variant 
FROM ODS.buildinfrastructure.SoftwareImageBuilds bsi
JOIN masterdata.softwareimages msi 
    ON msi.softwareimageid = bsi.SoftwareImageID
WHERE msi.SoftwareImage = 'WLAN.HL.2.0' AND 
    (BuiltBy = 'username1' OR BuiltBy = 'username2') and 
    Status !='Expired' 
ORDER BY Builton DESC
```

[image]

Comment: There's no `TOP` operator in MySQL. Are you using SQL-Server?

Comment: yup sorry...its `SQL SERVER`

Comment: Please add the desired result.

Comment: @McNets - The desired result is the top2 rows in the screen shot but we can't hardcode like Barmar suggestion below..need to calculate the count of variants from Buildinfrastructure.SoftwareImageBuilds for a given SoftwareImage

Comment: something like this: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=75dcd2d8b1b3b4f896bbac2412b8083a ?

Comment: change builton by builton desc

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that returns the number of variants each software image has, and another query that gets the number of variants across all software images.

```
SELECT TOP 10 SoftwareImageBuild si, variant 
FROM ODS.buildinfrastructure.SoftwareImageBuilds bsi
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(Distinct variant) all_variants
            FROM ODS.buildinfrastructure.SoftwareImageBuilds) av
JOIN masterdata.softwareimages msi 
    ON msi.softwareimageid = bsi.SoftwareImageID
JOIN (SELECT SoftwareImageBuild si, COUNT(*) variant_count
      FROM ODS.buildinfrastructure.SoftwareImageBuilds
      GROUP BY SoftwareImageBuild) bsi2
    ON bsi.SoftwareImageBuild = bsi2.si AND bsi2.variant_count = av.all_variants
WHERE msi.SoftwareImage = 'WLAN.HL.2.0' AND 
    (BuiltBy = 'username1' OR BuiltBy = 'username2') and 
    Status !='Expired' 
ORDER BY Builton DESC
```

Comment: we need to calculate the count for a given SoftwareImage..your query is assuming its `2`

Comment: You said "Only return rows with the number of variant count".

Comment: yes but you are hardcoding the variant count..we need to get that count dynamically from Buildinfrastructure.SoftwareImageBuilds for a given SoftwareImage

Comment: We're getting it dynamically with `COUNT()`, and then checking if it's the desired count that you only want to return.

Comment: I dont have a desired count..the count should be the one we get dynamically

Comment: Do you mean you want to include the variant count in the result, not restrict to software images with a particular variant count?

Comment: 1.Firstly the query throws an error `Invalid column name 'si'..` 2.why are you  doing `COUNT(DISTINCT variant) = 2`

Comment: I use MySQL, I forgot that SQL-Server doesn't allow `AS` before column aliases. Anyway, I think I understand what you want now, try it.

Comment: as you said it is in MYSQL and has syntax errors..is there a way you can convert to SQL-server

Comment: it thows a syntax error at `bsi.SoftwareImageBuild = bsi2.si AND bsi2.variant_count as av.all_variants`

Comment: I don't know SQL-Server, so I'm doing it by trial and error. I had a typo, `as` should be `=` in the last `ON` clause.

Comment: I dont know either...anyone else care to help to conver to SQL server?

Comment: why does it say `Error line 9: Invalid column name 'si'..` even though the column is present

Comment: I changed it to `SELECT SoftwareImageBuild si, COUNT(*) variant_count
      FROM ODS.buildinfrastructure.SoftwareImageBuilds
      GROUP BY si)` but this doesnt give the accurate account as it always be  1 since the softwareimagebuild is different

Comment: I think SQL-Server doesn't allow aliases in `GROUP BY`, I changed it to use the real column name.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Just put the code to create the table and fill in the contents in the left box, and the `SELECT` query in the right box.